# Push Notification not receiving in background but working in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

When my app is in foreground It can receive push notification in

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
                       didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);

}
```

Log in console -

```
{

    app =     {

        alert = dsafdas;

        badge = 1;

        sound = "myringtone.caf";

    };

}
```

But the problem is when the app is in background not showing push notification.

In the settings for the app

ALERT STYLE - `Banners`

Badge App Icon - `enabled`

Sounds - `enabled`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is: `app` should be `aps`

```
{
    aps :  {
```

Instead of

```
{
    app :  {
```

Answer (score 2):

`didReceiveRemoteNotification` gets called in `foreground`, when in bacground mode, user needs to tap to make the app active.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ){
      NSLog(@"app was already in the foreground");
    }
    else{
       NSLog(@"app was just brought from background to foreground");
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
}
```

Comment: So far I know `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called when app is in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

```
didReceiveRemoteNotification
```

Will work for sure(Like database operation or Network access). But it will not display log output until the app is in foreground.

N.B: To work on background you need to turn on the capabilities feature.

Comment: Yes log showing after opening app. problem was `app` it will `aps`.